# How to generate PDF reports querying specific set of data from databse using PHP/MySQL/FPDF?

Tags: php, mysql, report, fpdf

My project includes generating of complex reports based on user query, and printing it on an A4 size sheet, in a specific design. It also demands multiple data query, or group data query from users. For example - user might select all students above standard 3, so all data of students coming under this category should get selected and converted into a multiple page PDF report according to the predefined report design.

user does not want page by page printing because it becomes tedious when large data is required.

Please guide how should i proceed?

Comment: This is  very broad - it's more a project description than a technical question. What specific issue are you stuck with?

Comment: Not able to generate multiple print reports of A4 size at once instead of making them one page at a time.

Comment: This is not data mining. See Wikipedia. I therefore removed the tag.

Comment: Yeah i know.I just wanted a PHP plugin or library walkthrough for PDF generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://html2pdf.fr/de/default

Here is Html2PDF which is easy to use and it also offers good examples how it's been used =)

Just define something like a table and then output it formatted with css to an PDF file.

Comment: looking into it.is it free? Define a static HTML table or a looping dynamic PHP table?

Comment: looping a dynamic or define a static html table is possible and it's free.